# Get posts in a subcategory of a chosen parent

Tags: categories, taxonomy

Taking on legacy data I have the following structure

-Top level category (category)

-- Sub category (report)

--- Post

I want to get all posts in a particular top level category.

**The problem is all the posts are only assigned to Sub Categories, not their top level categories.**

I've tried the following:

```
function getPostsInCategory($category) {

    return get_pages(array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'child_of'      => $category, // e.g '3'
        'numberposts'   => -1
    ));
}
```

I use `get_pages` instead of `get_posts` because it seems to support heirachy better.

How can I get all posts that are in a "report" that is a child of my chosen category?

Comment: You're implementing categories as pages? In your example "Top level category" is a category or a page?

Comment: ignore the pages aspect, these are normal categories and posts we are referring to, however I read you can still use ``get_pages`` to get posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `get_posts` or (even better) custom `WP_Query` to query posts.

You can use `get_pages` to do this, but `get_pages` can't use `category` (or other taxonomies - just check it in WP sources) to filter results.

So your function should look like this:

```
function getPostsInCategory($category) {

    return get_posts(array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'category'      => $category, // e.g '3'  catgory is passed as 'cat' param of WP_Query, so it will display posts from children categories as well
        'posts_per_page'   => -1
    ));
}
```

Comment: Oh god I feel so stupid, I didn't realise it would find grandchildren, I thought the posts would have to be directly in that category for it to work. Thank you :)